# AMP: amp-accordion not working

Tags: amp-html

Can anybody provide a working example of an `amp-accordion`? When I try the example code from https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-accordion.html in an amp page that references

```
<script async custom-element="amp-accordion" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-accordion-0.1.js"></script>
```

in the header, I get the following two (disturbing) error messages:

```
The attribute 'custom-element' in tag 'amp-access extension .js script' is set to the invalid value 'amp-accordion'. (see https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-access.html)
```

and finally

```
The tag 'amp-accordion' is disallowed.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find an example on how to use amp-accordion here:
https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-accordion/

Answer (score 2):

[According to this page](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-accordion), it seems to be an experimental component and has to be [manually enabled here](https://cdn.ampproject.org/experiments.html) and in the console with the following line of javascript:

```
AMP.toggleExperiment('amp-accordion')
```

Comment: In addition to @Jupe's answer, you'll get the error ***The attribute 'custom-element' in tag 'amp-access extension .js script' is set to the invalid value 'amp-accordion'.***  when the attribute `type` is any value other than the required value: `application/json`. Error is also thrown when the `src` attribute for the script tag is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, that is all I need to know... will comment it out for a while and wait what happens with this component ;)

Answer (score 1):

While it is experimental it is necessary to enable it. Be aware that just toggleExperiment is not enough, you need to check that the experiment is not enabled yet. See example below.

```
<script async custom-element="amp-accordion" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-accordion-0.1.js"></script>
<script>    
    (window.AMP = window.AMP || []).push(function(AMP) {
       if(!AMP.isExperimentOn('amp-accordion'))
          AMP.toggleExperiment('amp-accordion');
    });
</script>
```

Also don't forget to add styles for it:

```
   <style amp-custom>
        section[expanded] span.expanded {
            display: block;
        }
        section[expanded] span.collapsed {
            display: none;
        }
        section:not([expanded]) span.expanded {
            display: none;
        }
        section:not([expanded]) span.collapsed {
            display: block;
        }
   </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `amp` JS and `amp accordion` JS inside head tag as given below

```html
<!--
  ## Introduction

  An accordion provides a way for viewers to have a glance at the outline of the content and jump to a section or their choice at their will.
-->
<!-- -->
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>amp-accordion</title>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <!-- ## Setup -->
  <!--
    Import the `amp-accordion` component.
  -->
  <script async custom-element="amp-accordion" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-accordion-0.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-accordion/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <style amp-custom>
  amp-accordion section[expanded] .show-more {
    display: none;
  }
  amp-accordion section:not([expanded]) .show-less {
    display: none;
  }
  .nested-accordion h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  amp-accordion#hidden-header section[expanded] h4 {
    border: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  
    <amp-accordion disable-session-states>
      <section>
        <h4>Section 1</h4>
        <p>Bunch of content.</p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h4>Section 2</h4>
        <amp-accordion class="nested-accordion">
          <section>
            <h4>Nested Section 2.1</h4>
            <p>Bunch of content.</p>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>Nested Section 2.2</h4>
            <p>Bunch of more content.</p>
          </section>
        </amp-accordion>
      </section>
    </amp-accordion>
</body>
</html>
```